# C# Mixing up 2 different Custom Label Class

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have a custom label class which allows label control to have 4 different backcolors. (this gives the possibility to fill each label backcolor with 4 colors in the same time using .percentageX property).
Everything working nice so far.

```
 public class CustomLabel: System.Windows.Forms.Label
    {

        private Color m_color1 = Color.LightGreen;  //first color
        private Color m_color2 = Color.DarkBlue;    // second color
        private Color m_color3 = Color.Gray;    // third color
        private Color m_color4 = Color.LightYellow; //fourth color?!
        private int Percentagex1 = 30;
        private int Percentagex2 = 20;
        private int Percentagex3 = 50;
        private int Percentagex4 = 0;

        public Color Color1
        {
            get { return m_color1; }
            set { m_color1 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public Color Color2
        {
            get { return m_color2; }
            set { m_color2 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public Color Color3
        {
            get { return m_color3; }
            set { m_color3 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public Color Color4
        {
            get { return m_color4; }
            set { m_color4 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }





        public int Percentage1
        {
            get { return Percentagex1; }
            set { Percentagex1 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int Percentage2
        {
            get { return Percentagex2; }
            set { Percentagex2 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int Percentage3
        {
            get { return Percentagex3; }
            set { Percentagex3 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int Percentage4
        {
            get { return Percentagex4; }
            set { Percentagex4 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }


        //public Labelhand()
        //{ 
        //}



        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * Percentagex1 / 100);
            int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * Percentagex2 / 100);
            int x3 = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * Percentagex3 / 100);
            int x4 = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * Percentagex4 / 100);

            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(m_color1);
            SolidBrush brush2 = new SolidBrush(m_color2);
            SolidBrush brush3 = new SolidBrush(m_color3);
            SolidBrush brush4 = new SolidBrush(m_color4);


            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, x, this.Height));

            g.FillRectangle(brush2, new Rectangle(x, 0, x2, this.Height));

            g.FillRectangle(brush3, new Rectangle(x + x2, 0, x3, this.Height));

            g.FillRectangle(brush4, new Rectangle(x + x2 + x3, 0, x4, this.Height));


            base.OnPaint(e);

        }


    }
```

Then, I got another custom label class, this one gives the labels nice rounded corners.

```
 public class RoundedLabel
    {
        [Browsable(true)]
        public Color _BackColor { get; set; }

        public RoundedLabel()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

      

        private GraphicsPath _getRoundRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
        {
            int cornerRadius = 15; // change this value according to your needs
            int diminisher = 1;
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            path.AddArc(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90);
            path.AddArc(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width - cornerRadius - diminisher, rectangle.Y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90);
            path.AddArc(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width - cornerRadius - diminisher, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height - cornerRadius - diminisher, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90);
            path.AddArc(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height - cornerRadius - diminisher, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90);
            path.CloseAllFigures();
            return path;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            using (var graphicsPath = _getRoundRectangle(this.ClientRectangle))
            {
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(_BackColor))
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, graphicsPath);
                using (var pen = new Pen(_BackColor, 1.0f))
                    e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPath);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, this.Font, this.ClientRectangle, this.ForeColor);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is also working nicely, we set --> label.backcolor = Color.Transparent;
and then the _backcolor property will show a label with rounded corners.

The question comes how to mix these 2 class together to get rounder corners with all 4 colors, but keeping all 4 rounded corners at all times.
I tried to declare the second class like this:

```
public class RoundedLabel: CustomLabel
```

Unfortunately, the rounded corners are then only available to the _backcolor property. And not to the color1,2,3,4 ones.
thanks all for any advice!